# Remove string from the beginning and the end of line keeping the ones in the middle (sed)

Tags: sed

I am have the following text:

```
>seq1
--A--CGT-A--
>seq2
-GA-T-A-CC--
```

I would like to remove all "-" from the beginning and the end of the lines, i.e., keeping the "-" between the letters. Expected output:

```
>seq1
A--CGT-A
>seq2
GA-T-A-CC
```

I have tried the following sed, but it deletes only the "-" from the beginning.

```
sed 's/^\(-\)*//'
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Use `sed -E 's/^-+|-+$//g' file`

Comment: or to keep it clear: `sed 's/^-*//; s/-*$//'` or `sed -e 's/^-*//' -e 's/-*$//'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed 's/^-*\|-*$//g' file
sed -E 's/^-*|-*$//g' file
sed -E 's/^-+|-+$//g' file
```

Each of the commands removes hyphens from the start and from the end of the lines. Note the `g` flag that enables multiple matching on the same line.

**To support cases with leading or trailing whitespaces,** add `[[:space:]]` / `\s`:

```bash
sed 's/^\s*-*\|-*\s*$//g'
sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*-*|-*[[:space:]]*$//g'
```

**Note**: `\s` and `\|` examples are only valid for GNU sed.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2XmfNe):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='>seq1
--A--CGT-A--
>seq2
-GA-T-A-CC--'
sed 's/^-*\|-*$//g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
>seq1
A--CGT-A
>seq2
GA-T-A-CC
```

Comment: I have tried all these options but it still removes only the "-" in the beginning of the lines. What do you think it might be happening?

Comment: @NathanHonorato Are you sure there are no leading/trailing spaces? Try `sed 's/^\s*-*\|-*\s*$//g'` or `sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*-*|-*[[:space:]]*$//g'`

Answer (score 0):

This removes leading and trailing dashes on every line not beginning with `>` (including indented `>`).

```
sed -E '/^[[:space:]]*>/!{s/^-+|-+$//}'
```

Consider allowing for indented dashes: `s/[[:space:]]*-//`.